# Back-projecting from image coordinates to world coordinates (with respect to the map)?

Tags: python, image-processing, camera, coordinates, projection

could you please help me with my problem? I have to do a back-projection from image coordinates to world coordinates, so with respect to the map. What I've done so far is using intrinsics to project the image into the camera and then change coordinate system with the extrinsics values. So I went from image to camera and then from camera to the ego-vehicle coordinate system. It is an automotive setting, so cameras are on the car and their values are given with respect to the vehicle while vehicle values are given with respect to the map (Nuscenes dataset settings). I can't use Lidar information and Nuscenes doesn't provide GPS coordinates. I can't use OpenCV too. I'm going to share my code (I even tried to follow this paper but the results were the same http://www.ce.unipr.it/people/bertozzi/publications/cr/iv2004-tracking-clermont.pdf):

```
                    cam_intrinsic = np.asmatrix(row[4])
                    center_x = cam_intrinsic[0, 2]
                    center_y = cam_intrinsic[0, 5]
                    focal_x = cam_intrinsic[0, 0]
                    focal_y = cam_intrinsic[0, 4]
                    averageheight = 1.75
                    depth = (averageheight*focal_x)/pixelcoord[2] #<- this is the height of the bounding box
                    # set z=depth from camera length and solve the other equations for x and y
                    cameracoord = np.array([((pixelcoord[0] - center_x)*depth) / focal_x,
                                            ((pixelcoord[1] - center_y)*depth) / focal_y,
                                            depth]).T

                    # Coordinate system origin in meters: x, y, z
                    translation = np.asmatrix(row[2])
                    #print(translation)
                    # system orientation as quaternion: w,x,y,z
                    orientation = np.asmatrix(row[3])
                    #print(orientation)
                    x = orientation[0, 1]
                    y = orientation[0, 2]
                    z = orientation[0, 3]
                    w = orientation[0, 0]
                    quaternions = (x, y, z, w)
                    #transformation from quaternion to roll,pitch,yaw value
                    euler = tf.euler_from_quaternion(quaternions)
                    roll = euler[0]
                    pitch = euler[1]
                    yaw = euler[2]
                    spatial_orientation = ct.SpatialOrientation(elevation_m=translation[0, 2], tilt_deg=pitch, roll_deg=roll, heading_deg=yaw, pos_x_m=translation[0, 0], pos_y_m=translation[0, 1])
                    spacecoord = spatial_orientation.spaceFromCamera([cameracoord])


                    ego_translation = np.asmatrix(data[2])
                    #print(translation)
                    # system orientation as quaternion: w,x,y,z
                    ego_orientation = np.asmatrix(data[3])
                    #print(orientation)
                     ego_x = ego_orientation[0, 1]
                     ego_y = ego_orientation[0, 2]
                     ego_z = ego_orientation[0, 3]
                     ego_w = ego_orientation[0, 0]
                     ego_quaternions = (ego_x, ego_y, ego_z, ego_w)
                     # transformation from quaternion to roll,pitch,yaw value
                     ego_euler = tf.euler_from_quaternion(ego_quaternions)
                     ego_roll = ego_euler[0]
                     ego_pitch = ego_euler[1]
                     ego_yaw = ego_euler[2]
                     global_orientation = ct.SpatialOrientation(elevation_m=ego_translation[0, 2], tilt_deg=ego_pitch,
                                                                        roll_deg=ego_roll, heading_deg=ego_yaw, pos_x_m=ego_translation[0, 0],
                                                                        pos_y_m=ego_translation[0, 1])
                     globalcoord = np.asmatrix(global_orientation.spaceFromCamera([spacecoord]))
```

So, what am I missing? Because with this setting points are projected on a plan and don't reflect the distribution around the car. Here is a plot:

[Left: Groundtruth - Right: My projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtOdl.jpg)

Thank you in advance.